# Grouping and summing a list into a map using Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a list of `MoveTrack` objects that i want to group by Month and count and store the data in a `Map<String, Double>`. I am trying to learn Lambda and experiment with it so trying to do this task with Lambda.

```
class MoveTrack {
private Date time;
private Double movementAmount;

//getters and setters
}

// in my main method
List<MoveTrack> mveTracking = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Double> movMap = new HashMap<>();
```

So I want to be able to group the `moveTracking` list and sum the values into the `movMap`, with each Map Key = Month Name (January, February, etc.) and corresponding Value the movement amount which is a sum of doubles for that month.

Comment: Well, have you tried anything yet? I suspect you want to use `Stream.collect` and `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Comment: And Collectors.summingDouble as downstream collector

Comment: @JonSkeet yes attempted groupBy and toMap with nothing but errors. Especially when i started putting in the simpledateformater.

Comment: So please show what you've tried, and what those errors are.

Comment: @JonSkeet all good, i needed a fresh perspective to determine if i was on a right path in the first place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) Allows you to reduce a list to a map where the key is some manipulation of the list's element and the value is some aggregate function applied to a manipulation of the element. 
In your case, you could use something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat monthFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
Map<String, Double> moveMap = 
    moveTracking.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                    (m -> monthFormatter.format(m.getTime()),
                     Collectors.summingDouble(MoveTrack::getMovementAmount)));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're open to using a third-party library, [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has specialized methods called `sumBy` that work well with lambdas.

If you use [`MutableList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html) from Eclipse Collections for the moveTracking list, the code would look as follows:

```
MutableList<MoveTrack> moveTracking = Lists.mutable.empty();
ObjectDoubleMap<String> doubleMap =
    moveTracking.sumByDouble(MoveTrack::getMonthName, MoveTrack::getMovementAmount);
```

It's up to you to determine where and how you want to implement `getMonthName()`.  You'll notice that `sumByDouble` returns an [`ObjectDoubleMap`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/map/primitive/ObjectDoubleMap.html).  This means you can use `double` for your `movementAmount` and it will not be boxed during the summing.

If you want to keep your `List<MoveTrack>` type as it currently is, you can either use a [`ListAdapter`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/mutable/ListAdapter.html) or the [`Iterate`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/Iterate.html) utility class to accomplish the same thing.

```
List<MoveTrack> list = ...;
ObjectDoubleMap<String> doubleMap =
    Iterate.sumByDouble(list, MoveTrack::getMonthName, MoveTrack::getMovementAmount);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 2):

Use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) as follows:

```
mveTracking.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> {
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(m.getTime());
            final int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month];
        }, Collectors.summingDouble(MoveTrack::getMovementAmount)));
```

**Code** for you ;)

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MoveTrack> mveTracking = new ArrayList<>();
        mveTracking.add(new MoveTrack(new Date(), 10.0d));
        mveTracking.add(new MoveTrack(new Date(), 11.0d));
        Map<String, Double> movMap = new HashMap<>();
        movMap = mveTracking.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> {
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(m.getTime());
            final int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month];
        }, Collectors.summingDouble(MoveTrack::getMovementAmount)));
        System.out.println(movMap);
    }
}

final class MoveTrack {

    private final Date time;
    private final Double movementAmount;

    public MoveTrack(final Date time, final Double movementAmount) {
        this.time = new Date(time.getTime());
        this.movementAmount = movementAmount;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public Double getMovementAmount() {
        return movementAmount;
    }
}
```